# Jackson: add key identifier to the JsonArray

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am creating JsonArray with the aid of jackson and I am trying to add a key `map_data` to the craeted JsonArray to send it as response to the Android app. How can I add it to the JsonArray?

I appreaciate any help.

```
{
  "map_data":
             [
               {"route": 2, "latitude": 89.667781, "longitude": 13.517741},
               {"route": 7, "latitude": 89.657772, "longitude": 13.537742},
               {"route": 9, "latitude": 89.647763, "longitude": 13.547754},
               {"route": 12, "latitude":89.637754, "longitude": 13.567765}
              ]

}
```

**Code:**

```
        Database db = new Database();
        List<MapData> lrl = db.get_map_data(selected);

        try {
            ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer()
                    .withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            String json = ow.writeValueAsString(lrl);

            System.out.println("The output of json: " + json);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ObjectWriter#withRootName(String)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#withRootName%28java.lang.String%29) to give a *root name*

> Method for constructing a new instance with configuration that
>   specifies what root name to use for "root element wrapping".

For example,

```
String json = ow.withRootName("map_data").writeValueAsString(lrl);
```

Comment: I ahve a simple question. Do I need to add the key for parsing purspose at the client side or I do not really need it ?

Comment: Since the key is now part of the JSON, your parser on the client side will need to know about it.

Comment: No it is not part of my json I thought I have to add it as I said to simple the parsing on the  client side.

Answer (score 0):

What you want as a result is a JSON object, containing a single field named map_data of type array. So that's what you should serialize instead of just serializing a list:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @JsonProperty("map_data")
    private List<MapData> mapData;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```